# Dictate using voice in Android

Tags: android, voice

When I dictate using voice in Android I would like to know some of the commands like "space" "new line" "comma" "new paragraph" 
Full stop or period works.

Any one know?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the handful of voice dictation commands that work on Android:

- Period (.)
- comma (,)
- question mark (?)
- exclamation or exclamation point (!)
- Line spacing: Enter or new line, new paragraph"

Source: [Use Voice Dictation to Save Time on Android, iPhone, and iPad](http://www.howtogeek.com/177387/use-voice-dictation-to-save-time-on-android-iphone-and-ipad/)

You can also find other useful commands in this.

Comment: Vote up and select my answer if it helped you. Members are required to vote up as **reputation** is what makes SU work. Never forget to select answers if you want to close the *topic* as some users may think that you haven't found a solution still. Participating by using your votes power will make us more willing to help you next time. Come back to SuperUser if you have any question of this type. :)

Comment: New users cannot vote up. It requires a certain reputation level. Also, you shouldn't prompt users to come back with questions that are actually off topic here (see [help/on-topic]). In fact, you should hesitate from answering such questions.